# Find an element of order $p+1$ in $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

The question says it all. I'm looking for an element of order $p+1$ in $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$. I have already computed the order of the group (so I know it's possible that one exists). I have also computed the number of elements of order $p$. I don't know how to go about this. Based on the case where $p=2$ I figure it should be something like

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$

but I can't seem to figure it out.